# What TLS version and ciphers does kubectl use?

Tags: kubectl

When kubectl connects to a cluster, I need to be able to see what TLS version it's using and what ciphers as well. I tried running with `-v=999`, but the debug output doesn't show that.  Is there a way to see that, please?

Comment: Could you provide more context? Could you share the command that you used? you only wanna know the communication between the `kubectl` and the cluster? Have you a service using the TLS?

Answer (score 0):

One way to check what tls version is using is connecting to the master node and at the path ***/etc/kubernetes/manifests***  and then run ***grep -i tls-min-version*** as described in [here](https://stigviewer.com/stig/kubernetes/2021-04-14/finding/V-242378#:%7E:text=during%20electronic%20dissemination.-,The%20Kubernetes%20API%20Server%20must%20use%20TLS%201.2%2C%20at%20a,sensitive%20data%20during%20electronic%20dissemination)

another thing that you can try is checking the cluster logs dump and see if you find what you need in there:
***kubectl cluster-info dump***

For reference you might want to check this [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/)